# Fast key generation for sorting matrices in python/C++

Tags: c++, sorting, matrix, key, ranking

Working in C++ and python, I am looking for a matrix function `f` (i.e., function that takes a matrix as input and returns a scalar value) that I can use to generate a key for sorting square matrices/2-d arrays with non-negative integer entries.

Example: I have a set of three (or more) matrices `A`, `B`,`C`... with `f(A)=a`,`f(b)=b`,`f(C)=c`... 
If `a<b<c`, the program returns the list `(A,B,C)`. If `b<a<c` the program returns the list `(B,A,C)`.

To ensure that this sorting procedure is reliable, I need that `f(A)=f(B)` if and only if `A==B`. I am looking for function that fulfills this condition and computes fast for matrices with up to 100 rows and columns.

Comment: What have you attempted? Seems like a difficult problem you have come up with.

Comment: @smac89 I tried an elementwise comparison (similar to what frg100 suggests). In python, the while loop takes its time if two matrices are very similar. So I was wondering if there is a way to make this more efficient (possibly using numpy array functions).

Comment: I should add in my program, the matrices `A`,`B`, `C` are all square matrices with the same number of rows and columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to correctly overload the < operator, your relation would have to be a strict weak ordering, meaning that, for it to be a strict order, it would have to be asymmetric and transitive, and for it to be a weak order, its incomparability relation must be transitive. In other words, this means that if you're comparing three matrices, A, B, and C, then your "<" cannot have both A

To satisfy that last requirement, the comparison of A and B must return "equal" only if the matrix A is the same as matrix B, which we know can only be true if every element of A is equal to every element of B. Taking this into consideration, we must use every element in the matrices to *ensure* that A and B returns "equal" only if the matrix A is the same as matrix B.

Consider the following function:

> 1. If matrix A has less rows than matrix B (return A is less than B)
> 2. If matrix B has less rows than matrix A (return B is less than A)
> 3. If they have the same number of rows, continue
> 4. If matrix A has less cols than matrix B (return A is less than B)
> 5. If matrix B has less cols than matrix A (return B is less than A)
> 6. If they have the same number of cols, continue
> 7. Iterate through every element in A
>
>    i. Compare the integer value at each position and the integer value
>      of B at that same position
>
>    ii. If element at A < element at B (return A is less than B)
>
>    iii. If element at B < element at A (return B is less than A)
> 8. If all entries are equal (return A = B)

This means that in the worst case, the function will have to check every element in the matrices, but in order for the < operator to be correctly overloaded, there is no other choice

In every other case, the function will return as soon as there is a difference in the elements which will be fairly quick most times